# Applied for a job without attaching resume

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Is there any way to view an application and edit it after the fact? I was so focused on the cover letter part that I clicked "Apply" as soon as I finished writing it but by the time I realized my mistake it was too late. I know that SO uploads a PDF copy of your developer story if you don't upload a resume, but I feel like there should be at least a prompt to make sure that's what you want to do if you click "Apply" without uploading a resume.

Comment: The question title reminds me [this](https://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/76195696/profound-advice-applied-for-job-without-attaching-resume.jpg)

Answer (score 13):

Thank you for your feedback.

We're aware that the user experience around application could be better, and we are considering some ideas to improve it that may help the concern you raise.  Also, a few minutes ago we launched a new feature: when you upload a resume and submit the job application, the resume you uploaded is saved for the next application.  That way, you have one fewer thing to remember in your later job applications if you want to keep reusing the same resume.

I know none of this helps your immediate problem, and I'm sorry you experienced it.  Our intent is to make the Developer Story a great replacement for your resume, so if you have completed your Story, we hope it will impress the employer you contacted regardless.

Comment: Awesome! That sounds like a great addition.

As it turns out, I was able to find an email address to send the resume to directly, so no harm done :) Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Actually, how difficult would it be to have a prompt to remind a user that he/she has not attached a resume? What is your point of view behind not being ready to make this modification. Actually, you could have a checklist somewhere showing what user has/doesn't have. When any items are absent, you could provide a prompt.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar That's probably not the modification we will make, to start.  We already validate required fields on the application form.  However, because we automatically attach the Developer-Story-generated resume for users who have a minimum-complete Developer Story, failure to attach a resume in this case does not cause a validation error.  Of the two approaches we might take to fix the problem -- neither of which is a prompt -- the cheaper one still requires _some_ design and development effort, and there are other competing priorities.